# How can a Vec be returned as a typed array with wasm-bindgen?

Tags: vector, rust, typed-arrays, wasm-bindgen

I have a `Vec` I would like to return and convert to a typed array with wasm-bindgen, ie, to turn a `Vec<u32>` into a `Uint32Array`. From my research it appears that wasm-bindgen cannot handle automatically converting these by itself right now (like it does for `String`) and instead you must use the [js-sys](https://crates.io/crates/js-sys) crate. I haven't found clear examples of *how* to use this crate however. It would be much appreciated if a clear simple example of how to use it could be provided.

For completeness' sake, it would be great if answers could explain both how to expose a function returning a `Vec<u32>`, as well as a struct member, ie, how do you convert these definitions into something that will work:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn my_func() -> Vec<u32> {
    inner_func() // returns Vec<u32>
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct my_struct {
    #[wasm_bindgen(readonly)]
    pub my_vec: Vec<u32>,
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what was the problem with `js-sys`? It's the regular crate so you can add it to the list of your crate's dependencies and then use it in crate's code.

Comment: @MaxV Yes, I know how to install it, I'm asking how to *use* it.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can use it like any other regular crate. For example you can create an array: `let array = js_sys::Uint32Array::new_with_length(42);` then put your values inside: `array.fill(13, 0, 41);` and finally return it from your function.

Comment: @MaxV Please read the question again, I don't know how it could possibly be any clearer. I'm asking how to take a `Vec<u32>` from somewhere else and expose it through wasm-bindgen. Using `js_sys::Uint32Array` from the ground up may work for some, but I'm asking how to convert a `Vec` in this question.

Comment: Got you. Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @MaxV Sorry if the question seemed really basic, and I guess it is, but I looked for examples quite a lot without finding anything I could make sense of. And it's good to have a reference question for this even if it is so basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert a `Vec<u32>` to a [js_sys::Uint32Array](https://docs.rs/js-sys/0.3.45/js_sys/struct.Uint32Array.html). So your `my_func` would look like:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn my_func() -> js_sys::Uint32Array {
    let rust_array = inner_func();
    return js_sys::Uint32Array::from(&rust_array[..]);
}
```

And the struct can be exposed by making a getter:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct my_struct {
    // Note: not pub
    my_vec: Vec<u32>,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl my_struct {
    #[wasm_bindgen(getter)]
    pub fn my_vec(&self) -> js_sys::Uint32Array {
        return js_sys::Uint32Array::from(&self.my_vec[..]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what stopping you from creating an instance of `Uint32Array`?

Comment: Ah thank you! This will be slow for long arrays however. Is there a way to copy the whole thing at once?

Comment: @curiousdannii, please check the new version :-)

Comment: Excellent! :D That's just what I was hoping would be possible. It ends up being quite concise.

Comment: By the way, a slice is a reference to values, so you don't "convert" something to a slice, rather you "create" a slice. You can create a slice of the entire vector using `&inner_func()[..]` and it doesn't need to be stored in an intermediate variable, so the entire body of the function can be reduced to just this line: `js_sys::Uint32Array::from(&inner_func()[..])` Note that `return` and the semicolon are also unnecessary.

Comment: Does the solution incur a copy?  If so, is there a way to expose a view into the WASM heap instead?

Comment: I don't know about a  way to expose a view into the WASM heap. It may be difficult to guarantee validity of the view anyway.